# JSON save selected items on array and pass to other page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

So I have 2 pages.
On one I have a table that is getting data from a JSON page and I inserted a button on each row that whenever is clicked it should get that item on an array.
And then, that array should give the results on the second page.

I can get the info from the JSON without problems, but cannot store the information on an array. Can someone help me? I'm quite new on JavaScript.

Page 1:

```
 <script>

<!-- Retrieve data from file -->
var products=[];
var cartArray=[];
var product_array=[];
$.getJSON('products.json',function(data){
    $.each(data.products, function(i, f){
        var img = f.image_url;
        var title = f.title;
        var price = f.price;
        var old_price = f.old_price;
        product_array.push([img, title, price]);

        var tblCell = "<tr><td class='prod_container'><tr><td class='prod_img_container'><img class='prod_img' src=" + img + "></td></tr>" + "<tr class='title_container'><td class='title'>" + title + "</td></tr>" + "<tr class='price_container'><td class='price'>" + price + "</td>" + "<td class='price_org'>" + old_price + "</td>" + "<td class='add_cart'><img class='add_cart_img' src='img/buynow-green-6.png' onClick='addToCart()'>" + "</td></tr>"

        $(tblCell).appendTo("#list_products tbody");
    });
}); 

<!-- Add To Cart -->
function addToCart(){
    cartArray.push([product_array.title, product_array.img, product_array.price]);
    window.alert(cartArray);
}

<!-- Store and go to checkout -->
function goToCheckout(){

    $('#store').on('click', function(){
        localStorage.cartArray = cartArray;


    });

    window.location.href="cart.html";

}
```

Comment: you want the data stored in a JavaScript or PHP array?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want localStorage.cartArray to look like?

Comment: Ohh. I do not really know. Is it better JS or PHP? I just want «the info on that row to be stored and passed into the next page when clicking another "final" button

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of your final data structure needs, but if you want a multi-dimensional array:

```
var cartArray = []
function addToCart(product_array){
    cartArray.push([product_array.title, product_array.img, product_array.price];
    window.alert(cartArray);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I did not use that correctly, because it did not work.

Comment: Well, there are a myriad of strange things in your code. Such as, how is your handler getting a reference to the cart item, and addToCart is not accumulative...and I'd think that title,img,price would be undefined.

Comment: hmm.. I thought that buy clicking on the button in the table, on the corresponding function, it would store the information of that same row. apparently that is a really stupid thought then.
the title, price and img are defined earlier.

Comment: See my change, I think this should give you want you want, assuming that product_array is getting passed as expected. Keep in mind variables inside of functions are local to that function. gotToCheckout can't see the variables inside addToCart. I moved cartArray up a level, and initialized it as empty array.

Comment: Ok. Thanks to your comment, I managed something more. I updated my former code. (thank you, i finally understood a bit more how it works). 
the problem now is that is giving blank, instead of showing the title, img and price.

Comment: Thats because you need a reference to the product info, which if I were you, I'd use html5 data attribute to store the data array for each button, and then in the handler, you can reference (event is passed to you as the first parameter of a click event) event.target to get the data attribute for that element. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: Although, I have the button on the JavaScript code, not on the HTML.